# wlan0 does not work.(eth0, wlan0 same netmask)

Tags: wireless, networking, ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

as wlan0 was connected to WiFi.

The ping is not a gateway for wlan0.

netmask of eth0 and wlan0 is the same.

```
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:b7:c3:04:e6:e0  
          inet addr:192.168.10.76  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::52b7:c3ff:fe04:e6e0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3901 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:388105 (388.1 KB)  TX bytes:41038 (41.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:54622 (54.6 KB)  TX bytes:54622 (54.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:f7:33:0e:26:3f  
          inet addr:192.168.3.5  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::caf7:33ff:fe0e:263f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3401231 (3.4 MB)  TX bytes:356442 (356.4 KB)

root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     9      0        0 wlan0
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# ping 192.168.3.1 -c 5
PING 192.168.3.1 (192.168.3.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.10.76 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.76 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.76 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.76 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.76 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.3.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3999ms
pipe 4
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# ifconfig eth0 down
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     9      0        0 wlan0
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# ping 192.168.3.1 -c 5
PING 192.168.3.1 (192.168.3.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.3.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=57.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.3.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=78.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.3.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=102 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.3.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=23.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.3.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=255 time=45.6 ms

--- 192.168.3.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.293/61.543/102.461/27.225 ms
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# 
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# ifconfig eth0 up
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     9      0        0 wlan0
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# 
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     9      0        0 wlan0
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon# ping 192.168.3.1 -c 5
PING 192.168.3.1 (192.168.3.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.10.76 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.76 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.76 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.3.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4022ms
pipe 3
root@kwon-530U3C-530U4C:/home/kwon#
```

Comment: The netmask doesn't matter when it comes to this.  They only decides which part of the IP address is network address and which is node address. But the `192.168.10.76/16` and `192.168.3.5/16` looks strange. How do you configure/manage the networks? With NetworkManager (NA) or with /etc/network/interfaces?  You should not use ifconfig(8) and route(8), they are deprecated. You should use ip(8) instead.
If you uses `/etc/network/interfaces` , you should use ifup(8) and `ifdown(8)`to start and stop an interface in `/e/n/interfaces`.  More information neede.

Comment: What is the router for `eth0`, it looks strange, as you uses `192.168.3.1` in some parts and `192.168.1.1` in others.  So which is the correct one?

Comment: I use the default Network Ui of Ubuntu.
/etc/network/interfaces is not used.
Yes. eth0 and wlan0 is a different router.
Windows7 is to operate in the same situation, but it does not work Ubnutu.

Comment: So you have 2 network cards that go to 2 different routers *on the same network*?  Windows allows you to have 2 default gateway addresses for 2 different network cards, whereas all other OSes only have 1 default gateway, so you should add a route for the specific network addresses you want to go out on the WiFi link...
Could you post an [infrastructure diagram](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/3jU4BYxnn5y9wzjHmDQGWTxVzhP9TuyykIsGeKpHCTY=w817-h578-no)?

Comment: OMG.... This Situation [infrastructure diagram](http://i.imgur.com/2t3LglV.png)

Comment: Any solution to the problem?

Comment: Sorry, the comment is late.
Yes. It has been resolved. the netmask of eth0 and wlan0 been set differently. Thank you very much glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set up for your net is clearly wrong.

If the routes for WiFi and Eth0 are on the same net, then the part of the IPv4 addresses that have binary 1 in netmask must be same, that is, the networks network address should be the same. If the two devices, WiFi and eth0, are on different nets then they must have different net addresses.

In your setup, the network address for both nets are `192.168.0.0/16`. So both units are on the same LAN. 
There are also only one default router in a system. That is where packets should be sent if you don't have any route specified for that address.

If you really want the two devices to connect to different LANs, then they have to be set to different networks. That is, in your case the net mask should be `255.255.255.0`, so `wlan0` is on LAN network `192.168.3.0` and `eth0` is on LAN network `192.168.10.0`, neither should be on the same LAN network `192.168.0.0` as it is now.

Please install the program `ipcalc` and try out different IP addresses and netmasks as arguments. That might help you.

Comment: You are welcome, @TaeYoungKwon.